# Handle Azure Devops pipeline resource over rest api

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline with the resource section is given below

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: test
    type: git
    name: Hackfest/template
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: Build
    source: mybuild
    branch: main
    # version:  # Latest by default
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - main
```

I'm trying to invoke the pipeline using a rest api call. The body of the rest api call is given  below

```
    $body='{
    "definition": {            "id": "3321"        },
     "resources": {
       "pipelines": {
         "Build": {
            "version": "20220304.15",
            "source": "mybuild"
           }
          }
        },
    "sourceBranch": "main"
```

}'

With the above json string I'm able to invoke the pipeline build, but it is not picking the artifacts from version 20220304.15 of the build "mybuild". Rather it is taking the latest artifact version of mybuild and starting the build.

How I should modify the above body string to pick the correct version of the "mybuild"?

Comment: with which api you invoke the pipeline?

Comment: my api-version is 6.0 and i'm using the invoke-RestMethod function

Comment: which api url? pipelines or definitions?

Comment: https://dev.azure.com/{{org}}/{{project}}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.0

Comment: tried with 6.0 and 7.0 and both didn't worked

Comment: is it yaml pipeline?

Comment: yes, it is  YAML pipeline

Comment: so try to use this api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

Comment: Great! you can accept my answer below :)

Comment: Done.
If possible mention about using the api in your answer  : learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/….
Because that was the real fix

Comment: I mentioned it.. it's link inside the "Runs - Run Pipeline".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) this is worked for me:

```
"resources":  {
                  "repositories":  {
                                       "self":  {
                                                    "refName":  "refs/heads/dev"
                                                }
                                   },
                  "pipelines":  {
                                    "Build":  {
                                                         "version":  "Build_202203040100.1"
                                                     }
                                }
              }
```